# How to disable text wrap in a columnar column?

Tags: python

```
|---------|------------------|------------------|-----------|------------------|
|serial no|ggggggg name      |status            |status code|AAAAAAAAAurl      |
|==============================================================================|
|1        |ggggggggggg-kkkkkk|Healthy           |200        |http://aaaaaaaaaaa|
|         |e                 |                  |           |-service.dev.sdddd|
|         |                  |                  |           |1.cccc.cc/health/l|
|         |                  |                  |           |ive               |
|---------|------------------|------------------|-----------|------------------|
|2        |zzzzzzzz-jjjjjj   |Healthy           |200        |http://ddddddddddd|
|         |                  |                  |           |ader.dev.ffffff.cc|
|         |                  |                  |           |cc.cc/health/live |
|---------|------------------|------------------|-----------|------------------|
```

I am trying to get the last column in one row the entire url. I am using the following python library to print this, tried few things but unable to get this working. I tried https://pypi.org/project/Columnar/ setting max column width and min column width and such as mentioned here, but none are working

Edit: Headers are simply names of the columns, you can name it anything you want

```
from columnar import columnar

headers = ['serial no', 'service name', 'status', 'status code']
...
tabledata = []
counter = 0

for x in services:
  zzz = requests.get("http://xxx.yyy"+ x)
  counter = counter + 1
  i = counter
  myrowdata = [i, x, zzz.text, zzz.status_code]
  tabledata.append(myrowdata)

table = columnar(tabledata, headers, no_borders=True, max_column_width=None)
print(table)
```

Comment: `headers` doesn't contain url, why?

Comment: You're also not including the url in the `tabledata` rows. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Try adding a `terminal_width` option and set it to a large value instead of letting it default.

Comment: Yes I tried all these options
table = columnar(tabledata, headers, no_borders=False, max_column_width=None, wrap_max=0, min_column_width=90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.)** You missed the column name `"url"` from `headers`.

You should do as follows:

```
headers = ['serial no', 'service name', 'status', 'status code', 'url']
```

**2.)** You have to add url to `myrowdata`:

```
myrowdata = [i, x, zzz.text, zzz.status_code, "http://xxx.yyy"+ x]
```

**Update:**

If you did all the fixes above, you have to run it in an **external system terminal** to get the real result, as some internal IDE console constrains the width of the display:

In Spyder:

```
  SERIAL NO  SERVICE NAME  STATUS   STATUS CODE     URL                         

  1          Anyname       Anytext  Anystatus_code  http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  
                                                    aadddddddddddddddddddddddd  
                                                    dddddddaaaaaaaaa.com
```

In external system terminal:
[image]

Comment: I forgot to add it in this question. I didn't miss it. Please check the output of the script. The things are getting printed fine, its just that they are not printing in one line

Comment: @sbolla Where you run this script, in what console?

Comment: when I use windows cmd prompt, I see the output correctly without line wrap. But in Azure console and Mobaxterm it wraps and is not very readable. Thanks for pointing out the terminal differences. Anyway I can workaround this goof

Comment: @sbolla You're welcome and please accept my answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @sbolla Sry, but you just upvoted my question with upper arrow, not accepted with check mark. :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. Did it